# What happens if I modify variable pointing to a cached rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching

I have a cached RDD which I use a couple of times inside a loop. At some point I modify the variable pointing to said RDD and then call that variable.

```
var rdd1 = someRDD.chache

do{
  val rdd2 = rdd1.someLogic
  val rdd3 = rdd1.someOtherLogic
  rdd1 = rdd1.someJoin(rdd4)
  val rdd5 = rdd1.someAggregateFunction
  rdd5.first //to start the transformations
  rdd1.unpersist
} while(someCondition)
```

My question is, at this point `val rdd5 = rdd1.someAggregateFunction` what would `rdd1` hold? `someRDD` or `rdd1.someJoin(rdd4)`? Do I need to unpersit it at some point before? Or do I need to cache it again if I'll use it again after `rdd5`?

EDIT
Something like this

```
var rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)).cache()
rdd1.collect().foreach(println)
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(4,5,6))
rdd1.collect().foreach(println)
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
4
5
6
```

So the values change. It still leaves the question of caching. Do I need to cache rdd1 every time I change it? If so do I need to unpersist it?

Comment: did you try it ?? If so, please share the results

Answer (score 0):

A cache should be like readonly copy,do not change cached RDD.Rather create a new rdd.

As far as i can understand,first of all you should not be doing unpersist in do while loop.That should be done after do while code.Also don't modify already cached RDD.I believe this is what you want.

```
var rdd1 = someRDD.chache
var changingRDD = null;
do{
  val rdd2 = rdd1.someLogic
  val rdd3 = rdd1.someOtherLogic
  changingRDD = rdd1.someJoin(rdd4)
  val rdd5 = changingRDD.someAggregateFunction
  rdd5.first //to start the transformations
} while(someCondition)
rdd1.unpersist
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. This way rdd2 and rdd3 will use the same rdd1 every loop, but I need them to use modified rdd1. I could assign 'changingrdd = rdd1' before the loop, but then I loose the benefit of caching.

Comment: In that case caching would not serve the purpose that you did earlier var rdd1 = someRDD.chache,as it is called only once.So don't need that code.Also rdd1 is declared var inside do while,you reference is changing to rdd1.someJoin(rdd4),

Comment: You mean don't need cache? And what do you mean only once? rdd1 is used 4 times in my example.

Comment: 1. Here cahcing is not serving your purpose.

Comment: Here caching is not serving your purpose.Lets say you created rdd1 with some value x (somerdd),then in do while rdd1 = rdd1.someJoin(rdd4) is changing the value of rdd1 to y and not to x anymore in 1st iteration of do while.In further iterations rdd1 y value is change to a,further iteration b ,c and so on.So caching is of no use to here.Caching would be helpful to you only if you were reading x always as value in rdd1 in the do while loop,but here you are changing rdd1 value every time in iteration.Hope you got the point.